# Justifying the closing of a letter using KOMA-script scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I try to have the closing of my letter justified just as the body of the letter using `scrlttr2`. It can seems to be a stupid question since the closing use to be something really short in English, but in French it is often something rather longer. In my case it is just a bit too long to fit on a single line.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[
  SN,%lco file for swiss letters (SN 010 130))
  refline=dateleft,
  firstfoot=false,
  enlargefirstpage,
  backaddress=false,
  foldmarks=false,
  parskip=half-
  ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Street\\My city}
\setkomavar{date}{Here, le \today}
\setkomavar{subject}{a subject}
\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedright}

\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{A Name\\An adresse\\A city}
\opening{Chère Madame,}

\blindtext

\closing{Dans l'attente de vos nouvelles, je vous prie d'agréer, Madame, mes meilleures salutations.}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I found how to make the closing ragged left or right but after hours of trying googleing and searching in the `scrlttr2` doc I did not found out how to do it.

BTW: I'm using version `scrlttr2 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (letter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined in your code with line

```
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}
```

to get an left justified signature including closing text.  Just change this line to:

```
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{}
```

then you will get the result you want.

Please see complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  SN,%lco file for swiss letters (SN 010 130))
  refline=dateleft,
  firstfoot=false,
  enlargefirstpage,
  backaddress=false,
  foldmarks=false,
  parskip=half-
  ]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My Street\\My city}
\setkomavar{date}{Here, le \today}
\setkomavar{subject}{a subject}
\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries\normalsize\raggedright}

%\renewcommand\raggedsignature{\raggedright}
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{A Name\\An adresse\\A city}
\opening{Chère Madame,}

\blindtext

\closing{Dans l'attente de vos nouvelles, je vous prie d'agréer, Madame, mes meilleures salutations.}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting closing text]

Comment: Wow ! That was simple ! I tried a lot of things with that code line but I never thought about letting the argument empty !